# Как реализовать такой стиль кнопки?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как можно реализовать такой стиль кнопки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используй Expression Blend+xaml для wpf, css+jquery для html. Какой язык программирования?)

Comment: А вижу Expression Blend тебе в помощь. Настраивай анимацию визуально да и всё Или вы хотите готовый xaml увидеть в ответе?

Comment: @cvvvlad, С Expression Blend пока что не работал, так что был бы не против увидеть готовый xaml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вот вам код, пробуйте:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                    <Ellipse Stroke="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"
                             StrokeThickness="2"
                             Fill="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}">
                        <Ellipse.OpacityMask>
                            <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="HighlightGradient"
                                StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" SpreadMethod="Pad">
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Ellipse.OpacityMask>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Fill"
                          Data="M 0 0 M 0.4 0.3 L 0.6 0.5 L 0.4 0.7 M 1 1"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightGradient"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="GradientStops[0].Offset"
                                        To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightGradient"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="GradientStops[1].Offset"
                                        To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightGradient"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="GradientStops[0].Offset"
                                        To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightGradient"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="GradientStops[1].Offset"
                                        To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Кнопка должна быть квадратной.

```
<Grid Background="Violet">
    <Button Height="100" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Результат (не умею вставлять анимацию):

[image: нормальное состояние] [image: mouse over]

---

Давайте попробую объяснить, что происходит в коде.

1. Мы делаем универсальный стиль, чтобы можно было применить к любой кнопке. В частности, мы не опираемся на реальные размеры, только на «квадратность».
2. Для того, чтобы поменять UI, нужно полностью переписать `Template`. Так и делаем.
3. У нас будет несколько элементов один на другом, поэтому `Template` начинается с `Grid`'а.
4. Сначала отрисовываем эллипс (окружность) белого цвета. С ней проблем нет.
5. Уголок вправо должен быть показан всегда, его рисуем последним через `Path`. Пользуемся тем, что `Path` умеет автоматически растягиваться под любой размер, устанавливаем координаты от 0 до 1, чтобы не привязываться к реальному размеру. Уголок `0.3, 0.3 -- 0.5, 0.5 -- 0.3, 0.7` смотрится уехавшим влево, двигаем его на 10% вправо, получаем `0.4, 0.3 -- 0.6, 0.5 -- 0.4, 0.7`.
6. Теперь нам нужен анимированный круглый фон между эллипсом и уголком. Идём на хитрость: отрисовываем эллипс, но «отключаем» его при помощи `OpacityMask`. Анимацией этой самой `OpacityMask` будем показывать/убирать фон. Цвет фона берём из системных ресурсов, чтобы не угадывать.
7. Позаботимся об анимации. Чтобы прозрачность «наползала» не сплошной линией, заведём две градиентные точки: первая указывает границу полностью непрозрачного, а вторая — полностью прозрачного участка. Между ними будет полупрозрачный фон. В начале обе границы установлены в 0, фон полностью прозрачен.
8. Теперь добавим анимацию. Нам нужен триггер по `MouseOver` (или что там вам нужно). При появлении `MouseOver` проигрываем анимацию, при исчезновении откатываем. Поскольку в момент начала анимации ещё может не закончиться предыдущая, не указываем `From`, а только `To`. В анимациях двигаем градиентные точки к 1. Для того, чтобы непрозрачная граница немного отставала от прозрачной, используем `EasingFunction`.

Всё!

Comment: У вас получилось еще красивей чем я хотел. А благодаря тому что вы всё расписали, появляется понимание как делать хорошие стили. Спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Вы меня захваливаете :) Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 4):

**Expression Blend** устанавливается вместе с VS обычно, посмотрите может он установлен у вас уже. Просто 
-откройте в нём свой проект, нужный файл. 
-Добавьте canvas. 
-В него ellipse(видимый border около 2px белый без заливки). 
-В ellipse добавьте path(путь для рисования стрелочки) с данными(гуглите язык path в wpf) или просто TextBlock со знаком ">" (белого цвета). 
-Перед TextBlock/Path добавьте еще один ellipse(только заливка синего цвета). 
-На Canvas(или на Grid если у вас CustomControl) вешаем триггеры запуска и остановки анимации.
-Создаем анимацию

Я дал вам путь для решения вашей проблемы. Если вы что-то хотите сделать - делайте. Если вы просто хотите готовый код - нанимайте фрилансеров и вообще НЕ парьте себе мозг программированием.

Comment: Спасибо. Не подскажете какой-то толковый курс по Expression Blend?

Comment: Да там изучать то нечего, там просто возможностей больше. Курс не изучал, просто работал с Photoshop и After Effects за счет этого интуитивно понятно всё. Если хотите сегодня вечерком специально сделаю видео-урок на эту тему=)

Comment: Так мое описание даже не столько на Expression Blend опирается, сколько просто дает направление действий. Все тоже самое можно через xaml сделать. Алгоритм тот же!

Comment: попробую реализовать через xaml. А видео-урок я б не против посмотреть)

Comment: Заметано! Ссылку на урок кину сюда.

Comment: 7 years later: видеоурок так и не сделал. да и нах этот бленд никому не нужен уже