# Собственный стиль Expander WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Подскажите как создать expander примерно такого стиля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или поделитесь хорошими статьями где описывается создание подобных вещей, тк гугл не выдает ничего годного...(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ну на самом деле всё не так сложно. На сайте есть довольно много примеров с переопределением шаблонов ([[1]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/501947/10105), [[2]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520886/10105), [[3]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/693610/10105)). Но давайте посмотрим, что можно сделать в вашем случае. Я приведу наброски решения, а остальное вы уж сами.

Итак, мы собираемся переделывать шаблон полностью. Для этого имеет смысл отталкиваться от готового шаблона и удалять ненужные куски.

Положите в Visual Studio пустой `Expander`, выделите его в визуальном редакторе (не в редакторе XAML), и в контекстном меню (или в меню «Format») выберите «Edit Template» → «Edit a Copy...».

[image: всё так шаблонно!..]

Вы получите стиль Expander'а, а также его вспомогательные стили и шаблоны, на которые он опирается. Вам придётся внимательно почитать эту простыню кода, чтобы понять, за что именно какая часть ответственна, чтобы правильно отредактировать её.

Ну что ж, давайте тащить бегемота из болота. У меня вышел такой набор стилей (нервным просьба не смотреть):

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#FF000000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#FF000000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Static.Circle.Fill" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke" Color="#FF333333"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#FF333333"/>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderRightHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TransformGroup.Children>
                                        <TransformCollection>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                        </TransformCollection>
                                    </TransformGroup.Children>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderUpHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TransformGroup.Children>
                                        <TransformCollection>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                                        </TransformCollection>
                                    </TransformGroup.Children>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TransformGroup.Children>
                                        <TransformCollection>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                        </TransformCollection>
                                    </TransformGroup.Children>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="MyCoolExpanderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                        <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Итак. Глядя в код триггеров `<Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">` и т. п., видим, что стили `ExpanderXXXHeaderStyle` отвечают за форму заголовка для случая нестандартного направления экспандера (вверх, влево, вправо). Поэтому стили `ExpanderRightHeaderStyle`, `ExpanderUpHeaderStyle` и `ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle` можно не думая удалять.

Разберёмся с `ExpanderDownHeaderStyle`, точнее, с его шаблоном. Мы видим внутренний `Grid` с одним отдельным столбцом для эллипса и уголка (`Path`), которые отрисовываются в стандартном экспандере:

[image: стандартнее не бывает]

— и вторым столбцом для контента. Нам ни уголок, эллипс не нужны, значит, можно убрать и `Grid`, и `Ellipse`, и `Path`, оставив только `ContentPresenter`. Триггеры внутри управляют видом эллипса и уголка, они тоже не нужны.

Получаем:

```
<Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

(Откуда у `Border` взялся `Background="Transparent"`? Он появился после экспериментов: если бы его не было, то нажатие по свободному месту экспандера не срабатывало бы. А с фоном hit test проходит нормально.)

Далее, несколько штук `SolidColorBrush` с именами наподобие `Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke` относятся к кругу и уголку, которые мы удалили, и тоже больше не нужны.

Теперь, что с `ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual`? Он используется так:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ... FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" .../>
```

то есть он — стиль для фокуса у экспандера. Если вы не хотите подсвечивать фокус, уберите его, но я оставил его как есть.

В стиле `MyCoolExpanderStyle` есть триггеры на `Property="ExpandDirection"`, их тоже можно удалить, т. к. мы всё равно не будем поддерживать 4 направления.

Отлично, мы уже убрали довольно много. Посмотрим теперь на желаемые изменения. Нам нужен красный фон, но наш фон определяется значением по умолчанию:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
```

Меняем его на `Value="Coral"` (точное значение спросите у графического дизайнера). Запускаем, видим:

[image: ну так себе, честно говоря]

Во-первых, нужно убрать закруглённые уголки. Они создаются в строке

```
<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" ... CornerRadius="3" ...>
```

Убираем `CornerRadius`.

Затем, чёрный фон для контента. Вместо обыкновенного `<ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite"` добавим окружающий `Grid` с чёрным фоном:

```
<Grid Background="Black" x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
    <ContentPresenter Focusable="false"/>
</Grid>
```

Запускаем, получаем:

[image: ну немного получше, но всё равно]

Сразу видим, что текста не видно. Ну да, текст-то у нас установлен чёрный (`<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>`, а нам нужен светлый. Берём вместо этого `SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey`.

Затем, у нас там был красный уголок, свисающий вниз. Дорисуем его. Это как раз просто: в `Grid` добавим `Canvas`, а в нём `Path` (геометрия `Path` подобрана экспериментально). Чтобы уголок не налазил на контент, добавим вертикальный `Margin` у `ContentPresenter`'а:

```
<Grid Background="Black" x:Name="ExpandSite" ...>
    <Canvas>
        <Path Data="M 20,0 L 50,0 L35,10 z" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stretch="None"/>
    </Canvas>
    <ContentPresenter Focusable="false" Margin="0,10"/>
</Grid>
```

Получаем:

[image: ну типа того]

Вот вроде бы и всё с экспандером, точные размеры вам придётся подправить самостоятельно. На всякий случай, вот весь полученный стиль: https://gist.github.com/vladd/9d67d8116c4d6f300d51814593e26bfd

Контент внутри экспандера — это какой-нибудь `ItemsControl`, его стилизовать проще (`ItemTemplate` и т. д.)

Comment: спасибо большое, очень достойный ответ!

Comment: @UporotayaPanda: Пожалуйста! Рад, если помогло!