# Как получить сылку на TextBox внутри CustomControl который наследуется от ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

**ОПИСАНИЕ**:
Мне нужно получить ссылку на TextBox  расположенный внутри ComboBox для получения контроля над событиями GotFocus и LostFocus именно данного элемента, поскольку меня не инетересует Focus всего ComboBox в целом.

Сначала я добился нужного результат создав UserControl внутри которого получил ссылку на TextBox используя:

```
comboBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", comboBox)
```

В UserControl все прекрасно работало.

После чего я решил сделать свой собственный CustomControl. Я хотел получить существующий функционал ComboBox плюс добавить свою логику. Для этого, я создал

```
public abstract class MeasureComboBox<InstanceT, EnumT> : ComboBox 
{
    // ...
}
```

в конструкторе данного абстрактного класса я хотел снов исользовать Template.FindName() для получения ссылки на TextBox но в этот раз данный метод возвращал null. Вот код конструктора в котором я использую данный метод:

```
public MeasureComboBox()
{
   this.TextBox            = this.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", this) as TextBox;
   this.TextBox.GotFocus  += TextBox_GotFocus;
   this.TextBox.LostFocus += TextBox_LostFocus;
}
```

**ВОПРОС**:
Не могли бы вы прокомментировать почему данный метод возвращает null и существует ли возможность получить ссылку на this.TextBox.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**:
При создании CustomControl мне нужна была существующая логика и действующий дизайн ComboBox. Поскольку изменений в дизайн я вносить не собирался я удалил из конструктора метод:

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MeasureComboBox<InstanceT, EnumT>), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MeasureComboBox<InstanceT, EnumT>)));
```

Вот неработающий пример CustomControl-а с моей проблемой. Я максимально упростил содержимое класса для того что бы показать конкретное проблемное место. При выполнении данного кода поле TextBox = null:

```
public class MeasureComboBox : ComboBox
{
    #region FIELDS
    /// <summary>
    /// TextBox that bilongs to ComboBox control. 
    /// </summary>
    private TextBox TextBox;
    #endregion

    static MeasureComboBox()
    {
    }

    public MeasureComboBox()
    {

    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        // Почему здесь возвращается null?
        this.TextBox = this.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", this) as TextBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что вы вызываете его в конструкторе. По идее, вы должны использовать OnApplyTemlate

Comment: @VladD  добавил в свой CustomControl:  public override void OnApplyTemplate() { this.TextBox = this.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", this) as TextBox; base.OnApplyTemplate(); } , по прежнему возвращает null.

Comment: @VladD попробовал применить эту же мысль к перегруженному Load() все равно не помогло.

Comment: Вроде бы в конструкторе обязателен вызов конструктора родителя, т.е. ваш конструктор должен быть записан в виде 'Combobox():base(){...}'. Какой-то из родительских конструкторов формирует детей и правильно добавляет их, насколько я помню. Проверьте.

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko: Тогда дайте воспроизводящий пример.

Comment: @VladD я добавил к вопросу, максимально упрощенный код CustomControla отражающий суть проблемы. Забавно, что прочитав ответы на похожий вопрос на англоязычной версии сайта, предложенный вами вариант решения по идее должен был решить проблему. Не могу понять почему данное решение не помогло мне. По идее должно было бы работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите свойство `IsEditable` в `true`, перегрузите `OnApplyTemplate`, и в ней вызывайте `Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", this)`. Будет работать.

---

Откуда взялась эта информация? В [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox?view=netframework-4.7) ничего такого не упоминается.

Давайте заглянем в стиль, который будет у нашего комбобокса. Это проще всего сделать как описано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/738993/10105). Мы увидим что-то наподобие (я убрал лишнее):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MeasureComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0" .../>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ...>
           ...
        </Popup>
        <ToggleButton ...>
            <ToggleButton.Style>
               ...
            </ToggleButton.Style>
        </ToggleButton>
        <ContentPresenter .../>
    </Grid>
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

Мы видим, что в шаблоне и правда нету части `PART_EditableTextBox`. А когда она появляется? Поискав строку `PART_EditableTextBox` в коде, находим ниже:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MeasureComboBox}">
```

То есть, для случая, когда `Editable == true`, выбирается другой шаблон. Смотрим в него (я снова убрал лишнее):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MeasureComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="Placement" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"...>
           ...
        </Popup>
        <Themes:ListBoxChrome .../>
        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" ...>
            ...
        </TextBox>
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"...>
            ...
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

Таким образом, в этом случае `PART_EditableTextBox` появляется. Итак, для того, чтобы у вас был нужный подконтрол, вы должны находиться в редактируемом режиме. Причём это не зависит от того, используете вы стоковый `ComboBox` или кастомизированный, т. к. стиль, который мы смотрим, унаследован вашим контролом от стандартного `ComboBox`'а.

Теперь можно убрать весь сгенерированный стиль (он нам больше не нужен) и просто установить `IsEditable="True"` в XAML или code-behind.

Comment: проверил, установив в конструкторе this.IsEditable=true... все работает!!! Спасибо!!

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko: Пожалуйста! Дописал ответ, добавил немного информации.