# WPF.4.0: Как замедлить ползунок в ProgressBar в состоянии IsIndeterminate

Tags: wpf, xaml, style, progress-bar

Использую .Net 4.0;

Хотел бы разобраться, как замедлить ползунок в WPF-овском  прогресс-баре, который в состоянии IsIndeterminate.

Могу сказать, что уже пытался делать. Нашел актуальную статью, но не имею опыта работы с анимациями, поэтому не разобрался.

1) Вот актуальная статья, но скачать пример там уже нельзя:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01cb9882-445b-473c-9057-336448f3c4a6/how-to-speed-up-progressbar-animation?forum=wpf

2) Взял оттуда:

```
<Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0"
       Storyboard.TargetName="PART_GlowRect"
       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
            <LinearThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="-100,0,0,0"/>
            <LinearThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="500,0,0,0"/>
        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
    </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

3) Скачал стиль с docs.microsoft.com.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/progressbar-styles-and-templates

4) Попытался использовать в этом в стиле ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames.

5) Так же пробовал скачать исходники ProgressBar-а из Microsoft, но там одно тянет другое, может быть есть вариант попроще... Тут в принципе не понятно, как качать source с дотнета, как ни качал всегда чего-то не хватает...

Comment: А почему бы вам просто не заставить Visual Studio отдать вам текущий стиль, как описано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/738993/10105)?

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, а в [этой](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/01cb9882-445b-473c-9057-336448f3c4a6/how-to-speed-up-progressbar-animation?forum=wpf) статье сказанно, что скорость указывается не в стиле: "unfortunately, the speed is hard coded in the behind code of the ProgressBar class, not in the template".

Comment: Хм, и правда, скорость установлена здесь: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ProgressBar.cs,227

Comment: Анимация запускается через `UpdateAnimation()`, который запускается через `IsVisibleChanged`. В принципе, можно сделать грубый хак: унаследоваться от класса `ProgressBar`, насильно отписаться от `IsVisibleChanged`, а взамен подписать свой обработчик вместо `UpdateAnimation()`, который сделает такую скорость, какую нужно. Единственная тонкость — нужно получить `_glow`, для чего придётся перекрыть `OnApplyTemplate`.