# Кастомный StackPanel неверно отображается

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю свой `StackPanel` с кнопкой для скрытия.

И вроде при запуске всё хорошо, но в конструкторе отображается не правильно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя должна быть ещё видна кнопка (запущенное приложение):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не то, что бы меня сильно волновала эта проблема, скорее просто неприятно.

Сам код:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace botDesing2 {
    public partial class ShowAnimatePanel : StackPanel {
        public ShowAnimatePanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool isContextHide = false;
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();

            if (isContextHide) {
                animation.From = ShowHideButton.RenderSize.Height + 6;
                animation.To = ContentPanel.RenderSize.Height;
                animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(350));
                ContentPanel.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, animation);
            } else {
                animation.From = ContentPanel.RenderSize.Height;
                animation.To = ShowHideButton.RenderSize.Height + 6;
                animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(350));
                ContentPanel.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, animation);
            }
            isContextHide = !isContextHide;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel x:Class="botDesing2.ShowAnimatePanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:botDesing2"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Name="ContentPanel"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         CanVerticallyScroll="True"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Border BorderBrush="#ffb2b2b2" BorderThickness="0,2,0,2"/>
<Button Name="ShowHideButton" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#ffb2b2b2" BorderThickness="2,0,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click">
    <TextBlock Text="Bots info" Foreground="#ffffffff" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="20"/>
</Button>
```

Как исправить проблему?

P.S. заодно скажите, адекватна ли вообще такая реализация кастомного `StackPanel`, или можно сделать лучше?

Comment: Наследоваться от панели в вашем случае нехорошо, вам нужен по сути UserControl, а не панель

Comment: @АндрейNOP дак мне нужна помимо контейнера ещё и кнопка, а если я буду использовать `UserControl`, то при помещении объектов внутрь `UserControl` кнопка продаёт.

Comment: Нет, почему же, добавите в разметку UserControl панель (Grid, например), в нее свою кнопку и место для остальных контролов. Панель в WPF не имеет визуального представления, она только занимается компоновкой, поэтому в вашем случае панель не подойдет.

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно поподробнее про "место для остальных контролов"? Этот контейнер для того и был создан, что бы в него кидать элементы, которые можно скрыть по нажатию кнопки. Какие будут внутри элементы и сколько - неизвестно. Проще говоря - такое использование `<local:ShowAnimatePanel> <Button/> <Button/> </local:ShowAnimatePanel>`

Comment: Хотя, как я понял вам нужен по сути Expander, так почему его не использовать? Просто переопределите ему шаблон

Comment: @АндрейNOP о боже, я полдня делал то, что уже и так существует -_-

Comment: Вот пример изменения шаблона: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/738965/218063